# Is it a bad practice to globally install eslintrc file

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I am trying to improve my Visual Studio Code development environment to have a default `.eslintrc.json` file.  The majority of times I create a new project, I forget to make a `.eslintrc.json` file.

To resolve this, I installed a .eslintrc.json vile in my root directory. Now, when I use VSC, it defaults to the .eslintrc.json file in my root directory.

1. Is this a bad practice?
2. I couldn't find an option in VSC to have a default `.eslintrc.json` file. Is there a better approach for having a default `.eslintrc.json` if one doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

There's a section of our [configuration docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy) that addresses your use case!

1. On any long-running project or one that multiple people will work on, it's generally better to have the configuration in the project directory so that the code doesn't become out of date as you update your global configuration and to be sure that everyone uses the same configuration for the project.
2. You can put your `.eslintrc.json` in your user home directory, and ESLint will look there as a fallback if it doesn't see any configuration files in a project.